# An alternative to Cayley Menger determinant for calculating simplex volume

Tags: euclidean-geometry, simplicial-volume

I recently came across the determinant of a symmetric $3\times 3$ matrix

$\begin{pmatrix} 
       2a^2& a^2+b^2-c^2& a^2+d^2-e^2\\
     a^2+b^2-c^2&   2b^2& b^2+d^2-f^2\\
     a^2+d^2-e^2& b^2+d^2-f^2&   2d^2\\
\end{pmatrix}$

from which the volume of $3$-dimensional simplices with weighted adjacency matrix

$\begin{pmatrix}
0&a&b&d\\
a&0&c&e\\
b&c&0&f\\
d&e&f&0
\end{pmatrix}$

can be calculated (cf e.g. [Trigonometry of a tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry_of_a_tetrahedron)).

That in combination with the rule of Sarrus yields a very compact formula for the volume of general $3D$-tetrahedra:

$288V^2 = 8a^2b^2d^2 + 2\big((a^2+b^2-c^2)(b^2+d^2-f^2)(a^2+d^2-e^2)
-a^2(b^2+d^2-f^2)^2 - b^2(a^2+d^2-e^2)^2 - d^2(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2\big)$

**Questions:**

- is there a name for the above $3\times3$ matrix or determinant?
- is it older or younger than the Cayley Menger determinant?
- does it generalize to higher dimensions and if yes, how?

Another mystery to me is why the Cayley Menger determinant seems to be folklore while the more "compact" alternative appears to be largely unknown.

Comment: This determinant is due to William H. McCrea and appears in his book on Analytical Geometry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what is it that you call the Caley-Menger determinant, but its [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Menger_determinant#Definition) seems to define it by a formula generalizing yours to arbitrary dimension.

This is arguably much better known than the other version of Caley-Menger determinant, under the name of [Gram determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix#Gram_determinant). To derive this determinant from Gram determinant, observe that $2\langle v_{0i},v_{0j}\rangle=\|v_{0i}\|^2+\|v_{0j}\|^2-\|v_{ij}\|^2$ (where $v_{ij}$ denotes the vector between $i$-th and $j$-th vertex), and that the volume of an $n$-simplex is $1/n!$ times the volume of the corresponding parallelotope.

As for the history, Caley-Menger's determinant was published by Caley (in his very first mathematical paper!) in 1841, and Jørgen Pedersen Gram was born in 1850 and introduced his determinant in 1879. However, Caley *did not* point out that his determinants give volumes of simplices, only that they vanish whenever points lie in a smaller dimensional subspace. It should be noted that the first calculation of a volume of a tetrahedron in terms of distances between vertices is [due to Piero della Francesco](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath424/kmath424.htm), in 15th century.